# Insert a node at nth vs beginning position LinkedList in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So I was watching [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbvsNF22Ud0&index=7&list=PL2_aWCzGMAwI3W_JlcBbtYTwiQSsOTa6P) about linked lists in C and was bashing my head against the wall to understand the logic of it.

What I would like to point here, is that in video (6) on how to insert node at beginning we have this:

```
void Insert(int input)
{
 struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
 newNode->data = input;
 newNode->next = start;
 start = newNode;
}
```

It gets work done and on printing we got this:

```
  Insert(10);
  Insert(20);
  Insert(30);
  Insert(40);
  Print();

40 30 20 10
```

And in video (7) on inserting note at nth positing we have this:

```
void Insert(int input, int position)
{
  struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  newNode->data = input;

  if (position == 1)
  {
    newNode->next = start;
    start = newNode;
    return;
  }

  struct Node *runner = start;

  for (int i = 1; i < position-1; i++)
  {
    runner = runner->next;
  }
  
  newNode->next = runner->next;
  runner->next = newNode;

}
```

And printing we having this:

```
  Insert(10,1);
  Insert(20,2);
  Insert(30,3);
  Insert(40,4);
  Print();
10 20 30 40
```

Which is inverted!
I was trying to trace why this is happening and found that the bug is here:

```
runner->next = newNode;
```

Where we assigning the address of the new node as next to existing node. It works perfectly if new node is inserted in middle of linkedlist, but if it inserter at the beginning the list gets inverted.

So I was wondering, how can I get rid of this inversion and which way is right?

Comment: A simple linked list is typically in reverse order of insertion. The new node is placed at the front of the list. But why do you think the list is "inverted"? The nodes were inserted at specific locations.

Comment: Why do you think the prints are "inverted"? They look right to me. Also Insert at position might want to check if you've reached  the end of the list instead of assuming the user will pass a valid position.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I think you're right.
It seems inverted, when we assign next of existing node as newly inserted node.
But, yes, if I would insert new nods always at first position it seem working good without being "inverted".

Comment: Perhaps you should count the nodes from the other end, that is, downwards from the `start` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was my logical misunderstanding.
When one is inserting nodes at nth position, according to @WeatherVane, list is actually gets reversed of order of insertion. (first in - first to print)

To get it in sequence where "first in - last to print" we need to stack nods at the beginning:

```
  Insert(10,1);
  Insert(20,1);
  Insert(30,1);
  Insert(40,1);
  Print();
40 30 20 10
```

Instead of:

```
  Insert(10,1);
  Insert(20,2);
  Insert(30,3);
  Insert(40,4);
  Print();
10 20 30 40
```